# How to access onBindViewHolder's items RecyclerView in an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerView` set up with my `adapter.` I used `interface` to listen for click events which helps me get the position and view of each  item.

However, I also need to access the `array` items inside the `onBindViewHolder` method. Is there a way I can make the method available too?

**Interface**

```
public interface ItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(View view, EpisodeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position);
}
```

**Adapter**

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Episode episode = postList.get(position);
        final String title = episode.getTitle();
        final Long timeStamp = postList.get(position).getTimestamp();
        holder.setTitle(title);
//how to make this method and items accessible by my activity
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private View mView;
        private CardView mParent;
        private TextView mTitle, mMonth, mDate;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            mTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            mMonth = mView.findViewById(R.id.month);
            mDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            mParent = mView.findViewById(R.id.parentView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setTitle(String text){
            mTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            mTitle.setText(text);
        }
        public void setDate(String text){
            mDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            mDate.setText(text);
        }
        public void setMonth(String text){
            mMonth = mView.findViewById(R.id.month);
            mMonth.setText(text);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (itemClickListener != null) {
                itemClickListener.onItemClick(v,  getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener((view, position) -> {
//only view and position available. how to access view holder items
            }
```

Comment: you will be getting every item clicked from the list in clicklistener. If you want listofItems you should have it already it this Activity because you passed that list from Activity to adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the signature of your ItemClickListener to support passing the clicked item to class that is implementing your callback. Try changing the listener to something like:

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(YourItem item);
}
```

When you are overriding `onClick`, pass the item by doing something like

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (itemClickListener != null) {
        itemClickListener.onItemClick(postList.get(position));
    }
}
```

You can find out more about this technique here: https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/